# Apartment Gem: One of the following schema(s) is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, apartment-gem

when doing `rake db:migrate`, I am getting this error:

> Migrating alpha tenant One of the following schema(s) is invalid:
>   "alpha" "public"

My apartment initializer configs:

```rb
require 'apartment/elevators/subdomain'
# require 'apartment/elevators/first_subdomain'

#
# Apartment Configuration
#
Apartment.configure do |config|

  config.tenant_names = YAML::load_file('./config/site-settings.yml').symbolize_keys

end 

# Rails.application.config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::Domain'
Rails.application.config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain'
```

Comment: Please post your `db/schema.rb` and whichever migration file under `db/migrate/` is causing the error.

Comment: There is no migration that causing the error. Its something related to apartment tenants configuration.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

**I ran into the same issue, and the solution here helped me**

I simply added an `after_create` callback called `create_tenant` to the model of the subdomain for my multi-tenant, which is `user.rb` in `app/models/user.rb`

Find below a link on Stackoverflow for the detailed answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57771338/10907864

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by:

1. logging into Postgres CLI: `sudo -u postgres  psql`
2. then connecting to the right database: `\c databasename;`  (to view all existing databases, run: `\l+`)
3. viewing all existing schemas:  `\dn+;`
4. After realizing that the schema in question was wrongly named (it had an extra underscore, while the name of the tenant didn't have it), I altered the schema as necessary: `ALTER SCHEMA old_name RENAME TO new_name`

After this, everything got back to normal.