# Apartment: TenantNotFound - One of the following schema(s) is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, apartment-gem

I am using the [Apartment Gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) for the first time for Multitenancy in a Ruby on Rails project. I am trying to create multiple tenants for users in your digital library Rails application.

I am using [Devise Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for the authentication of the application, and I have generated the and I have generated config file by running the code below in my terminal

```
rails generate devise:install
```

I have also generated a **User** model for **Devise** using the code below in my terminal

```
rails generate devise User
```

And for the **Apartment Gem**, I have installed it and generated the config file by running the code below in my terminal

```
bundle exec rails generate apartment:install
```

I have also configured the `config/initializers/apartment.rb` initializer file as needed using the documentation provided, and I have created a new tenant via my signup page at

```
localhost:3000/users/sign_up
```

But when I try viewing the newly created tenant at

```
http://newtenant.lvh.me:3000/
```

I get the error below

> Apartment::TenantNotFound(One of the following schema(s) is invalid: "" "public")

I have tried to figure out the cause of the issue, but I still haven't been fortunate to get it fixed. I need some help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how I fixed it**

I simply added an after_create callback called `create_tenant` to the model of the subdomain for my multi-tenant, which is `user.rb` in `app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_tenant

  private

  def create_tenant
    Apartment::Tenant.create(subdomain)
  end
end
```

Use this if you used **Devise** for Authentication

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_tenant

  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  private

  def create_tenant
    Apartment::Tenant.create(subdomain)
  end
end
```

**N/B:** My model name for the Tenant is **User**, your model name may be different, so check through your `app/models/` to see the model name that you used for the **multi-tenant**

You can try creating new tenants again, and everything should run fine.

This advice below may apply to only those who used **Devise** for authentication or to every other person using an authentication system

If you run into any issue like this

> Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

when trying to fix this issue of **Tenant Not Found**, simply restart your local server by using the code below

```
rails server
```

and then visit the link below to edit your newly created users/tenant

```
localhost:3000/users/edit
```

**N/B:** The `users` in `localhost:3000/users/edit` represents the plural name (table) of the model that I used for my multi-tenant.

When the page opens up, simply **Delete/Cancel the Account** and then that you've created already.

Now you can try creating new tenants again, and everything should run fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**